# How to open current directory in File Explorer by vim?

Tags: vimscript, gvim

> The problem is solved

> My purpose is that: I use vim to edit my m-file and debug it in Matlab. There is no easy-to-use interface plugin between vim and Matlab in Win10. So I just edit m-file in vim and run it in Matlab. Sometimes these m-files may be in different directories, so this function can help me to find them quickly.

My system is Win10, and I use gvim.

In vim, I know `pwd` and `cwd` in command mode can get the current directory.

And `:let g:myvars=expand('%:p:h')` to pass the directory to vim script variable.

I also know `:! some_cmd_command` to execute the cmd command in vim.

I want to implement such a function, that is, let vim open the file manager of the current path,
How should I do? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @statox I need a file explorer to call other programs on my computer. ```:Explorer``` is useful to help me edit the files, but it's too difficult for it to startup other programs.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my first comment just before you answered. I hadn't understood you were talking about the OS's file explorer but it's clear now :)

Comment: Whether or not you can vote, you can accept an answer (though only one) and that is a good way to say thank you. Edits to the post are, well, not

Comment: @HewieDing I just noticed your addition to your question. You're welcome. I upvoted your question so you now have enough rep to upvote whatever answers you feel merit it (and then you can remove the thanks from your question per DBK's comment). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use following to open directory where current file is and select it if possible:

```
"" Open explorer where current file is located
"" Only for win for now.
func! File_manager() abort
    " Windows only for now
    if has("win32")
        if exists("b:netrw_curdir")
            let path = substitute(b:netrw_curdir, "/", "\\", "g")
        elseif expand("%:p") == ""
            let path = expand("%:p:h")
        else
            let path = expand("%:p")
        endif
        silent exe '!start explorer.exe /select,' .. path
    else
        echomsg "Not yet implemented!"
    endif
endfunc

nnoremap <silent> gof :call File_manager()<CR>
```

The thing you might be interested in is `silent exe '!start explorer.exe /select,' .. path` which starts explorer and selects the path provided.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since your command contains a dynamic element (IOW it's not made up entirely of static strings) you'll need to build it with [`:execute`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#:exe).

Assuming [`'shell'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shell%27) and [`'shellcmdflag'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27shellcmdflag%27) have the defaults for win32 (`cmd.exe` and `/c`, respectively) then this will work:

```
exe '!c:\windows\explorer.exe ' . expand("%:p:h")
```

If `c:\windows` is already in your PATH envvar then you can leave off `c:\windows\`.

Prepend [`silent`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#:silent) to the above and the extra console window that pops up will be dismissed automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Simply `!start %:p:h` should be enough.

However, normall you'd better make use of some builtin "file explorer" plugin. Be it standard `netrw` or something else. There's rarely a benefit in spawning a full-featured Windows Explorer window.

Comment: There is a benefit for sure. For example I run asciidoc->pdf conversion and then would like to send pdf file. So I open file explorer from within vim and copy&paste&email&whatever.

Comment: @MaximKim I said "rarely", not "never". Also, all this could be done within Vim too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gvim, you can simply type `:browse e` in command mode 
you will have a mini-file explorer opened with current directory